# Asian characters on files name with subversion

Tags: svn

I check out the files from a subervesion repository and it finishes ok. But when I do the command `svn status` it says that there is a missing file: `새 텍스트 문서.txt`and also says that I have this file but it doesn't belong to the repository. What can I do to remove this file from the reposioty?
I have a mac and I check out via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, using quotes worked perfectly fine with the command line, the problem was with svnX.